# woocommerce - get total cart price excluding tax

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce for Wordpress to build a webshop.

In the checkout, I want to include the total price excl tax. How do I do this? I've found things like 'get_total_ex_tax()', but it doesn't work. Maybe i'm formatting it wrong, or in the wrong place or something. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the code to show total excluding tax before tax is displayed

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'output_total_excluding_tax' );
function output_total_excluding_tax() {
  ?>
  <tr class="total_ex_tax">
    <th>Total Excluding Tax</th>
    <td><?php echo WC()->cart->get_total_ex_tax(); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: Does it work on Wordpress 5.8 and 5.7? I applied the snippet but it doesn't seem to work.